# How to get the variable real type using JavaSymbolSolver

Tags: javasymbolsolver

The code is here,

```
class Bar {
    private int a;
    void aMethod() {
        while (true) {
            String a = "0";
            a = a + "1";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the real type of a. I tried to use the code below,

```
public class GetTypeOfReference {
     private static final String FILE_PATH = "src\\com\\test\\Bar.java";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         TypeSolver typeSolver = new CombinedTypeSolver();

         JavaSymbolSolver symbolSolver = new JavaSymbolSolver(typeSolver);
         StaticJavaParser.getConfiguration().setSymbolResolver(symbolSolver);

         CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(new File(FILE_PATH));

         cu.findAll(AssignExpr.class).forEach(ae -> {
             ResolvedType resolvedType = ae.calculateResolvedType();
             System.out.println(ae.toString() + " is a: " + resolvedType.describe());
         });

      }
}
```

But got the error,
Exception in thread "main" UnsolvedSymbolException{context='null', name='String', cause='null'}
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.JavaParserFacade.convertToUsage(JavaParserFacade.java:509)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.JavaParserFacade.convert(JavaParserFacade.java:567)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.declarations.JavaParserSymbolDeclaration.getType(JavaParserSymbolDeclaration.java:146)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.model.resolution.Value.from(Value.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.tryAdvance(LinkedList.java:1253)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:476)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.contexts.AbstractJavaParserContext.solveWithAsValue(AbstractJavaParserContext.java:149)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.contexts.StatementContext.solveSymbolAsValue(StatementContext.java:135)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.resolution.SymbolSolver.solveSymbolAsValue(SymbolSolver.java:68)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.resolution.SymbolSolver.solveSymbolAsValue(SymbolSolver.java:73)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.TypeExtractor.visit(TypeExtractor.java:277)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.TypeExtractor.visit(TypeExtractor.java:44)
    at com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.NameExpr.accept(NameExpr.java:79)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.TypeExtractor.visit(TypeExtractor.java:98)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.TypeExtractor.visit(TypeExtractor.java:44)
    at com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:135)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.JavaParserFacade.getTypeConcrete(JavaParserFacade.java:448)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.JavaParserFacade.getType(JavaParserFacade.java:310)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.javaparsermodel.JavaParserFacade.getType(JavaParserFacade.java:292)
    at com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.JavaSymbolSolver.calculateType(JavaSymbolSolver.java:250)
    at com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.Expression.calculateResolvedType(Expression.java:564)
    at test.GetTypeOfReference.lambda$0(GetTypeOfReference.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at test.GetTypeOfReference.main(GetTypeOfReference.java:31)

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is late but for those who are interested this is the right approach.
With javaparser 3.16.1 the result is

```
a = a + "1" is a: java.lang.String
```